# Error running PHP function more than one time from a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want the user to be able to go forward and backward through the date on button press. The problem now is it works one time, (the date goes forward one day) but on continued button clicking the date continues to stay the same... I want it to continue up as the user keeps clicking.

I have heard a few people say I should use AJAX. Okay, I can do this, but how would I do this so that submits it to the new page and only runs that one function. Please provide code examples! Thank you so much!

```
<script>
    function checkTime() {
            <?php timeSelect(); ?>;
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "<?php echo $dateSelect?>";
    }
</script> 

<?php
    function timeSelect() {
                static $extraDays = 1;
                global $dateSelect;
                $dateSelect = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("+" . "$extraDays" . " day"));
                $extraDays++;
                }
?>
```

Comment: Ajax can let you run the same php script and over again, once you get a hang of it tho. Brush up on you Ajax, see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: PHP and javascript can't interact interact in this way. A web page's PHP environment is dead and buried before the page appears in the browser. AJAX allows same/other PHP script to be triggered from a web page, and for that script to deliver text/data back to the displayed page. You need to learn AJAX. This is not the right place to provide such a tutorial. Plenty of online resources exist.